# TBitmap disappears on Android resuming App

Tags: android, delphi, bitmap, paint

I'm trying to use bitmaps in Android, but unfortunately I am having some problems.

I Created a TComponent customized inside with a TBitmap that is drawn with the Paint event:

```
  TMyThumbnail = class( TControl )
  private
    FBitmap: TBitmap;
  protected
    procedure Paint; override;
  public
    constructor Create( AOwner: TComponent ); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

constructor TMyThumbnail.Create( AOwner: TComponent ); 
begin
  inherited;
  FBitmap := TBitmap.Create;
end;
destructor TMyThumbnail.Destroy; 
begin
  FBitmap.Free;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TMyThumbnail.Paint;
begin
   Canvas.BeginScene;
  try
    // * On Resume App the FBitmap is not Empty! 
    if ( not FBitmap.IsEmpty ) then
      // ** So FBitmap is not empty and Width/Height are correct but is drawn as empty or nothing happens !
      Canvas.DrawBitmap ( FBitmap, TRectF.( 0, 0, FBitmap.Width, FBitmap.Height ), ClientRect, 1 ); 
  finally
    Canvas.EndScene;
  end;
end;
```

When assign or load a bitmap, everything proceeds normally, the component draws the bitmap properly.

**The problem** occurs when I go out from the app and call or opening another app / intent to my external app.

Returning in the app the bitmap is not empty and has the correct size, only that is not drawn with the call:

```
Canvas.DrawBitmap (FBitmap, BitmapRect, ClientRect, 1 );
```

Any suggestions?
Thanks.

Comment: I think I understand that using the Assign indeed in Android does not allocate physical memory but only the reference. Instead, using the function CopyFromBitmap apparently works.

FBitmap.CopyFromBitmap( );